# Worst case of Slowsort

Tags: code-golf, sequence, sorting

### Background

[Slowsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowsort) is an in-place, stable sorting algorithm that has worse-than-polynomial time complexity. The pseudocode for Slowsort looks like this:

```
procedure slowsort(A[], i, j)          // Sort array range A[i ... j] in-place.
    if i ≥ j then
        return
    m := floor( (i+j)/2 )
    slowsort(A, i, m)                  // (1.1)
    slowsort(A, m+1, j)                // (1.2)
    if A[j] < A[m] then
        swap A[j] , A[m]               // (1.3)
    slowsort(A, i, j-1)                // (2)
```

- (1.1) Sort the first half, recursively.
- (1.2) Sort the second half, recursively.
- (1.3) Find the maximum of the whole array by comparing the results of 1.1 and 1.2, and place it at the end of the list.
- (2) Sort the entire list (except for the maximum now at the end), recursively.

The recurrence relation of the worst-case time complexity (the number of swaps when the condition for (1.3) is always true<sup>1</sup>) is:

$$
\begin{alignat}{5}
T(1) &= 0 \\
T(n) &= T\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right) + T\left(\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil\right) + 1 + T(n-1)
\end{alignat}
$$

The first 50 terms of the sequence are:

```
0, 1, 3, 6, 11, 18, 28, 41, 59, 82,
112, 149, 196, 253, 323, 406, 507, 626, 768, 933,
1128, 1353, 1615, 1914, 2260, 2653, 3103, 3610, 4187, 4834,
5564, 6377, 7291, 8306, 9440, 10693, 12088, 13625, 15327, 17194,
19256, 21513, 23995, 26702, 29671, 32902, 36432, 40261, 44436, 48957
```

This sequence seems to coincide with [A178855](https://oeis.org/A178855).

A proof by @loopy wait (which gives rise to multiple alternative formulas):

> Proof: start with [A033485](https://oeis.org/A033485) (`a(n) = a(n-1) + a(floor(n/2)), a(1) = 1`) and verify that `a(2n+1)-a(2n-1)=2a(n)` (because `a(2n+1) = a(2n) + a(n) = a(2n-1) + 2a(n)`). Also verify that if `n` is even `2a(n)=a(n-1)+a(n+1)`. If we substitute `b(n)=a(2n-1)` we get `b(n)-b(n-1)=b(floor(n/2))+b(ceil(n/2))` which is already similar to T. If we now set `2T+1=b` we get back the recurrence defining `T`. As the initial terms also match this shows that `T(n)=((A033485(2n-1)-1)/2` which (shifted by one) is also given as a formula for A178855.

### Challenge

Evaluate the sequence \$T(n)\$. [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) default I/O applies; you can choose one of the following:

- Without input, output the entire sequence \$T(1), T(2), T(3), \cdots\$ infinitely
- Given \$n > 0\$, output \$T(n)\$ (corresponding to \$n\$th value under 1-indexing)
- Given \$n \ge 0\$, output \$T(n+1)\$ (corresponding to \$n\$th value under 0-indexing)
- Given \$n > 0\$, output the first \$n\$ terms, i.e. \$T(1), T(2), \cdots, T(n)\$

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

---

<sup>1</sup> Don't ask me how, I don't know if it can actually happen.

Comment: Shouldn't `T(1) = 1`? Because otherwise, the entire sequence is just 0s `T(2) = T(floor(1)) + T(ceil(1)) + T(1) = 0 + 0 + 0 = 0`

Comment: @lyxal You missed `+1` in the middle.

Comment: Ah my bad - mobile didn't show the scroll bar on the bottom :p

Answer (score 14):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 31 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to [@xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor).

```hs
a=s 0b
b=s 1$b<*"  "
s=scanl(+)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P9G2WMEgiSsJSBmqJNloKSkoKHEV2xYnJ@blaGhr/s9NzMxTsFUoKMrMK1FQUShJzE5VMDJQSPwPAA)

[A178855](https://oeis.org/A178855) is the cumsum of [A033485](https://oeis.org/A033485), while A033485 is the cumsum of `1, a(1), a(1), a(2), a(2), a(3), a(3), ...`, where `a` is A033485 itself.

Comment: You can do `b<*"  "`. Also you can remove the space after the `0`

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 31 bytes

Returns the \$n\$-th term, 0-indexed.

```javascript
f=n=>n&&f(n>>1)+f(--n>>1)-~f(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBDkAwEADvfcWepM1mBVfavwgqRHYFcRG@vtRpJpOZ27Pdu21aD2LpB9Xo2QfOsmg5hNJhtES/0fMlp1E2y@ChqIGhgSoR0cFlADrhXZYhX2S0mG5Xm1tf)

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 12 bytes

```
∫Θ¡§+→ȯ→←½;1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HH6nMzDi08tFz7UdukE@uBxKO2CYf2Whv@/w8A)

Uses the idea of the Haskell answer.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>14</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
λN<2÷₅+}.¥
```

-4 bytes porting [*@alephalpha*'s Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237804/52210) and combining it with [*@ovs*' 05AB1E approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237810/52210) of using `n-1`, so make sure to upvote both of them as well!

Outputs the infinite sequence.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3G4/G6PD2x81tWrX6h1a@v8/AA)

**Explanation:**

```python
λ        # Start a recursive environment,
         # to output the infinite sequence
         # Starting at a(0)=1 implicitly
         # Where every following a(n) is calculated by:
 N<      #  Push n-1
   2÷    #  Integer-divide it by 2
     ₅   #  Pop and push a((n-1)//2)
      +  #  Add it to the implicit previous item: a(n-1)+a((n-1)//2)
}        # After the recursive environment
 .¥      # Prepend 0 and get the cumulative sum of this list
         # (after which the infinite sequence is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 34 bytes

```c
f(n){n=n?f(n/2)+f(--n/2)-~f(n):0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHbTuswEHznK1aVkBKaCHt9SUzo4eGIr6B9qFIHKiBFTSSqU5VPP2E2tAUieTU7mdmLXeePdT0MTdKm@3bW3gFcczptkjwXkH/InxtVHYZ129Prct0mKe0vCJ8QcfcW6z6uHhY0o73KSGdkMvIAQLrMiHEssAsZlSy8BItMB8jYQW4YwSqkThVwM1DhYQzGjA5AbUSpvXbi1BZW9mjIfqyglUSvlXQrUcSWBhrnPKI3BZiCA@YojfQJ1sqwygcpyqocO3iW4s4w1LrQwUordjKmdhpKNiE46VkobMHBF7IvB8mMt4ZlDfYgrbXGyxTBFYdqvK9603Y91U/L7RVirJ/j9uvaJvPdPc934S@Om2T0MzeTo7vZbCmRK1@3q7iDTVVHeEvd@l/cNMnpMdLrI3F1ZiqaTkf16fFOD9ij0vij@kV3oJukT3@zEez5xUfX4lvwtoWkSSaXK8r/EOJlN2@xTZ9Rl50X7mazuDiWPVwchv9187J87Ib8/RM)

Returns the \$0\$-indexed \$n^\text{th}\$ term.

Uses given formula.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal 2.4.1](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>19</s> <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
λċ[½₌⌈⌊x$xn‹xṠ›|0
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%CE%BB%C4%8B%5B%C2%BD%E2%82%8C%E2%8C%88%E2%8C%8Ax%24xn%E2%80%B9x%E1%B9%A0%E2%80%BA%7C0&inputs=4&header=&footer=)

Of course just as I decided to make `Ṡ` no longer sum the stack, an edge case where it's needed pops up.

### Explained

```
λċ[½₌⌈⌊x$xn‹xṠ›|0
λ                  # Start a monadic lambda taking argument n that:
 ċ[                #    if n != 1:
   ½₌⌈⌊             #        push the ceiling and floor of (n / 2)
      x$x          #        and call this lambda on both
         n‹x       #        then call this lambda on n - 1
            Ṡ›     #        finally, push the sum of the stack + 1
              |    #    else:
               0   #        return 0
                   # The lambda is automatically called on end of execution
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 15 bytes

```
HḞ,ĊƊ;’ß€S‘µ0’?
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCJI4bieLMSKxoo74oCZw5/igqxT4oCYwrUw4oCZPyIsIiIsIiIsWyIxMCJdXQ==)

I don't think this is close to optimal.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

Implements the recurrence relation

```
0λND<‚;ï₅O+>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4NxuPxebRw2zrA@vf9TU6q9t9/8/AA)

Comment: Ah, of course. Decreasing `N` by 1 before halving.. Now that I see it, I can't believe I missed something so obvious. Nice answer! You can actually save an additional byte with [`0λ>ND<‚;ï₅O+`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4NxuOz8Xm0cNs6wPr3/U1Oqv/f8/AA) (EDIT: which you've already figured out I see)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 42 bytes:

```
f=lambda n:n and-~f(n//2)+f(~-n//2)+f(n-1)
```

Comment: -3 using routine golf tricks: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qz84wMS9FwVA7TSNPX99IE0jX6cJYebqGmvlFCnn/00CkQmaeQlFiXnqqhqGhplVBUWZeiQZQjabmfwA

Comment: actually, -4 https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qz84wMS9Fty5NI09f30hTO02jThfGytM11MwvUsj7nwYiFTLzFIoS89JTNQwNNa0KijLzSjSAajQ1/wMA

Comment: -9 https://tio.run/##NclBCoAgEAXQq8xyhhCxdkKHmTBLqK@ImzZe3dq0e/DK086MZYy4XnpvQQkepAimR4a1s0yRu/kF42TEXAmUQFVx7Oyc@FITGn8vMl4

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 33 bytes

```
.+
$*
+`1(1*)(1*\1)
$1$2¶$1¶$2
¶¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYtLO8FQw1BLE4hjDDW5VAxVjA5tUzEEYiOuQ9sObfv/38QSAA) Outputs the 0-indexed `n`th value. Explanation: Uses the recurrence relation given in the question.

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
+`1(1*)(1*\1)
```

Find the floor and ceiling of half of `n`.

```
$1$2¶$1¶$2
```

Replace `n` with `n-1` and the above two values. This introduces two extra lines for each recurrence.

```
¶¶
```

Count half of the number of extra lines, which represents the number of `1`s summed as part of the recurrence.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 56 bytes

```rust
fn f(n:i32)->i32{if n>0{f(n/2)-!f(!-n/2)+f(n-1)}else{0}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU/LbtswELzrK9a5hEJpl1w@JCpoDv2E9gMCJaYKITKtkBRaQNC3u0vXcQ8kh7OzM7txSfmyJA8pH7tuPHfd92X44fvjU3UZAgwsdKPCev9M9zoOEJ7FSuRXonYD2@0L@kLEXtabn5JfxbaVxlM/BlbDWgEM5whs5P7P7N@yP9Ywhv9pBIrwMJ3f3ulJ8zRm9vrIH@uDD8vJxz77mw/A5DN82nRAE8E3@JnjGH513RDPp5clDy37VByW8Dv2M6vrOzqQ@ETP3MdEtnf@6W4ffVqmTL4DG6FPJeRWnSknT2HHHtbtgd@Et1qfko/5xX/s2D@e3@e8KrZqqy6Cg@SgOFgChGTLAelowsZxaJFXUiIVNP2kIxkakiukSwv6GtFQNxJqLDU6pa4dBKUqSmmlKZ1SUytaCkR7dZCi3FaKktaSiW6V5pUxlpRWNcQ06GiOVpUcp3UZVlhXTFG01wSLxdwoJLVspCMD6dCUMaWRpETlnCmZjaAt0Nmm7Iuu/JTVCssaaInUWitbpnCm@Qs)

Returns the \$n\$-th term, 0-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
ＦＮ⊞υ∨¬υ⁺⌈υ§υ⊘⊖ＬυＩ↨¹υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYw7DsIwEER7TuFyLZkCiQal4lMQCYKvYJyFRPIHrXej3N4kMNXozdP4wZHPLtT6yqSgTR/hTuITCbRWVsoAYtSDoMsMoo2yQQrc3TxGiT9w5Db1OK/a1YUJe7igJ4yYeOk3TG9ePvQ/zcbSmBjOrjCcXEHYGbWOTa37Q91O4Qs) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the 0-indexed `n`th value. Explanation:

```
ＦＮ
```

Input `n` and loop that many times.

```
⊞υ∨¬υ⁺⌈υ§υ⊘⊖Ｌυ
```

Generate the next term of `A033485`, or `1` if there are no terms yet. (Annoyingly the formula for this sequence assumes 1-indexing.)

```
Ｉ↨¹υ
```

Sum the terms (using base `1` in case there are none).

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>38 ...</s> 35 bytes

```ruby
f=->n{n<2?n:f[n/2]-~f[n-=1]+f[n/2]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6vOs/GyD7PKi06T98oVrcOSOvaGsZqQ/i1/wsUNAz09AwNNPVyEws01NI0/wMA)

Recursive version, as a function, returns nth value.

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```ruby
*r=a=b=c=0;loop{p c;a,b,*r=r+=[c+=a-~b]*4}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X6vINtE2yTbZ1sA6Jz@/oLpAIdk6USdJByhepG0bnaxtm6hblxSrZVL7/z8A)

Non-recursive version, faster, prints whole list.